# what is this code: Func < T, string > that I don't understand

Tags: c#, asp.net, delegates

I have some code (not writted by me) that I don't understand:

```
private Func<ControllerContext, string> ThemeSelector { get; set; }
```

So this is not a **type**, this is **Func < T, string >** and I don't know how this kind of thing is named but I am unable to find some explanations on Google. Does someone can gives me some explanations of giving me a link to explain?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you checked MSDN OR ASP.net?

Comment: This might be a duplicate of this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901609/theme-selector-idea-for-a-blog-engine-written-with-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @Floradu88: I try to find by myself but I don't know how it is named so it is difficult to search... On msdn it is not clear for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Func<ControllerContext, string>` is a specific type of the generic `Func<T,K>`.
You need to learn about generics first before you can fully understand that.

Therefore ThemeSelector is just a property of that type, which has setter and getter.

The Func type is a delegate type, which represents a function that takes one parameter of type T and returns an instance of type K.

This means that you can assign any such function to the property. E.g.:

```
private string MyFunction(ControllerContext context) {
    return "Hello world!";
}

...

ThemeSelector = MyFunction;

Console.WriteLine(ThemeSelector(null));
```

will print "Hello world!" in the console.

Comment: +1 for code that almost gives an example that matches the question

Comment: Thank you guys, this one was the most relevant to me.

Answer (score 3):

This is a delegate type, i.e. this is a property and it can be set. And it can be called as method.

for example

```
/* Action<String> is a delegate, get it as an object*/
public void Foo (String[] arr, Action<String> instruction) {
    foreach (var element in arr) {
        //use it as a method
        instruction(element);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

The same applies to Func

```
// Func<Int32, Boolean> means that this is a function which accepts one argument as an integer and returns boolean.
public void Foo(Int32 data, Int32 otherData, Func<Int32, Boolean> instruction) {
    var result1 = instruction(data);
    var result2 = instruction(data2);
    Console.WriteLine(result1==result2);
}
```

**EDIT**

Even more comprehensive example.

```
//This methods accepts the third parameter as a function with 2 input arguments of type
// Int32 and return type String
public static void DoSomething(Int32 data1, Int32 data2, Func<Int32, Int32, String> whatToDo) {
    var result = whatToDo(data1, data2);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

public static Main(String[] args) {
    // here we are calling the DoSomething and
    // passing the Concat method as if it was an object.
    DoSomething(1, 2, Concat);
    // The same with multiply concat.
    DoSomething(7, 2, MultiplyConcat);
}
public static String Concat(Int32 arg1, Int32 arg2) {
    return arg1.ToString() + " " + arg2.ToString():
}
public static String MultiplyConcat(Int32 arg1, Int32 arg2) {
    return (arg1 * arg2).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a type ! Actually it a **delegate** type. It represents a method that can be used without explictely declaring a delegate.

The type is a generic type. The one in your example  is of type `Func<T, TResult>`, which represents a method that have one parameter of type T and returns a value of type TResult. Specifically to your example, it represents a method that have a `ControllerContext` parameter and returns a `string` value:

```
string ThemeSelectorHandler(ControllerContext context) {
    returns context.ToString();
}
```

Further reading:

- [Func Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx)
- [Generics in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172192.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

*A delegate is a pointer to a function.
*Func is a build-in delegate type. The last type in the angle brackets is the result type.
*Inheritance: Object-> Delegate-> Func
*Action is the build-in delegate pointing to a function without return.